# How to add more properties for the same node through CSV file in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say initially create Order nodes through the csv file orders.csv

```
// Create orders
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///orders.csv' AS row
MERGE (order:Order {orderID: row.OrderID}) 
  ON CREATE SET order.shipName = row.ShipName
```

Later I added more columns to the orders.csv, and I suppose I can add new properties into the graph this way:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///orders.csv' AS row
MERGE (order:Order {orderID: row.OrderID}) 
  ON CREATE SET order.shipName = row.ShipName, order.customerId = row.CustomerID, order.employeeID = row.EmployeeID;
```

Here two new properties 'customerId' and 'employeeId' to be added to each node of Order. I tested this command, but it doesn't change the graph at all. Does merge function incrementally add into to the graph?

Answer (score 0):

MERGE works on exactly the expression you provide it, so

> MERGE (order:Order {orderID: row.OrderID})

will check for a node with the label `Order` and an `orderID` property set to the value (and type) of `row.orderID`. If this doesn't exist exactly, it will be created.

Because you are using `ON CREATE...` that line will only occur if the node is being **created** by the merge, not if it is simply found (matched).

You probably want to look at using `ON MATCH...` instead - https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#query-merge-on-create-on-match

Answer (score 0):

[ON CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-create) is only used by `MERGE` when it needs to *create* something.

On the other hand, [ON MATCH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-match) is used by `MERGE` when it does not need to create anything.

So, your new query should look like this (assuming that you added no new rows to the CSV file, but only columns):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///orders.csv' AS row
MERGE (order:Order {orderID: row.OrderID}) 
  ON MATCH SET order.customerId = row.CustomerID, order.employeeID = row.EmployeeID;
```